# pass an array to action using ajax YII

Tags: ajax, yii, yii-events

Hi i'm really new with YII, please help me to solve a simple problem.
I'm trying to pass some values from js to action and then to put them into database.
Most of this code i got from tutorial

```
public function actionInsert(){
    $post = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = CJSON::decode($post, true);
    $read = new Read();
    $read->attributes = $data;
    $response = array();

    $read->save();
}
```

Then i send:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/read/insert/",
            data: "name=imja&short_desc=korotkoe&author=avtor&image=photo",
            error: function (){
                 alert('Error');
            },
            success: function(data){

            alert('success');

            }
    });
```

But i get an 'error' alert and nothing goes to DB.

Comment: in url do Yii::app()->createUrl('read/insert')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values from .ajax don't get submitted as a JSON array, the values should simply be in the `$_POST` array. Also I like to return something like 'complete'. Try changing your code to this:

```
public function actionInsert(){
    $read = new Read();
    $read->attributes = $_POST;
    $response = array();
    $read->save();
    echo 'complete';
    die();
}
```

Or you can send it as a JSON array from the javascript side:

```
var data = {
    name: 'imja',
    short_desc: 'korotkoe',
    author: 'avtor',
    image: 'photo'
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/read/insert/",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    error: function (){
         alert('Error');
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

However even if you do this apache will see the header type and still populate the `$_POST` array correctly. So it really isn't needed.

Also if you haven't already install Firebug onto Chrome or Firefox so you can see that actual ajax calls in the console. See what error you are getting from your action function in your controller.

Comment: Pitchinnate, it does work!!! Thank You! But the problem is: how i get values from the Post i got in controller? when i write $name = $_POST['name']; i get a 500 IntServerErro

Comment: Solved the problem! Thanks!